# Django command "python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput" scrambling .py files when copying files to s3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am trying to using **Django** collectstatic to send my script.py file to **AWS S3**. That file is then read by **AWS Glue** to execute Spark Job.

When i manually upload the *script.py*, **AWS Glue** can read it properly.
When i use the following command to send my script to **AWS S3**, the *script.py* gets scrambled

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Attaching screenshot of AWS Glue Edit Script for [reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAC3R.png)

I have tried changing the script.py to have only few imports and a print, That works and AWS Glue is able to read the script.py

Then i tried to add a few more *print* statements, then it scrambles.
It is difficult to conclude, exactly when it scrambles, as sometimes adding a couple of *import* in *script.py* also scrambles.

Anyone faced this?

**Observations :** Django compresses the file to 898 B, manually uploading the file keeps the file at 3KB. Although downloading the compressed file renders a proper file with size of 3KB.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue.

The *collectstatic* command compressed the file with

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Most browser reads the metadata and runs gunzip to inflate and show the file normally. **AWS Glue** is unable to read such meta and ends up scrambling the data.

**Solution :**
Need to provide AWS Glue uncompressed scripts, by excluding *.py* files during compression in *collectstatic* command.